# Create random number different from the numbers inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array for example [2,8,5,6], and I want to generate a random number different from the numbers that are inside the array, and that this number is not greater than 100.

Many thanks friends

Comment: Please show what you tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Set to avoid collisions

```js
arr = [2, 8, 5, 6]

getRandom = (exclude, min = 0, max = 100) => {
  let rand = Math.random() * 100 | 0
  while (exclude.has(rand)) rand = min + Math.random() * max | 0
  exclude.add(rand)
  return rand
}

arr = new Set(arr)

console.log(getRandom(arr))
console.log(getRandom(arr))
console.log(getRandom(arr))
console.log(getRandom(arr))

console.log([...arr])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could generate an array of the numbers up to the max that you want, then remove the ones that you don't want, and the pick a random element from the resulting array, for example:

```js
const max = 100
const exclude = [2,8,5,6]
const randomIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max + 1 - exclude.length))
const randomNum = [...Array(max + 1).keys()].filter(k => !exclude.includes(k))[randomIdx]
console.log(randomNum)
```